# How to show the original form after hiding it to pop up another form?

Tags: c#, forms, multiple-forms

I created a form which, when a specific button is clicked, pops up another form and hides itself. I don't now how to make it pop back up anymore, and I am trying to figure it out. 
Button click code:

```
BlackJack game = new BlackJack();
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    game.Show();
}
```

Main function code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Start());
}
```

2nd form closed event handler:

```
public BlackJack()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(game_FormClosed);
}
void game_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Option 1: Alter your constructor for BlackJack to take your Start form as a parameter (`BlackJack game = new BlackJack(this)`). Store this in a field and then in the closed event, call Show() on this object. That will cause the start form to be displayed again. Option 2 call ShowDialog() on game instead of Show(). Then in the next line of code re-show start.

Comment: Thanks for the Help.